# Activate iPhone with any sim?

Tags: iphone, cellular-carriers

I have bought an unlocked iPhone 5s (I believe it's model A1530) from the Apple Store Australia, can I use any sim to activate this phone?

Could I even use my partners and then put it back in his phone once it's activated?

I only want to use the phone over wifi for now.

Comment: I realize it's ironic to suggest you call for help without an activated phone, but did you consider calling Apple at their pre-sales number 133-622 if you're not clear about the activation steps or requirements?

Comment: All I'm wanting to know is if I can use any sim to activate the phone with until I receive my sim in month or so.

Comment: (Sorry keep pressing enter) it is a factory apple unlocked phone so will work on a variety of carriers. I'm just wondering if I can borrow a friends sim for instance for the activation phase. I then plan to use the phone over wifi until I receive my sim.

Comment: If your phone is factory unlocked, I believe you can activate it for use without any sim card in the slot. I'd answer that, but I'd hate to give you unconfirmed information as I've not seen a truly unlocked 5s yet here in the US. You would perhaps have to clear the other phone number from your phone, but once activated and without SIM, it would function well in WiFi mode.

Answer (score 4):

If the device is unlocked you can borrow a sim to activate the device. One thing to keep in mind though is you may want to skip setting up iCloud until after you remove the borrowed sim card.

After you've ejected the sim go into *Settings > Phone > My number*. Either clear the number out (which will be the number of your borrowed sim) or type in your actual phone number. The reason being is iCloud (specifically, iMessage) will want to tie the phone number from the borrowed sim to your iMessage account. It could potentially end up with you receiving iMessages intended for the person you borrowed the sim from.

Answer (score 0):

When you borrow a sim card from somebody to active your phone it will say Type in your Icloud you type in their icloud if not icloud it may so aol it will not affect their sim card or phone. After that go to setting and delted their icloud and make yours.